# Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'increment_id' in where clause is ambiguous after SUPEE 6788

Tags: magento-1.8, order-grid, supee-6788, grid-layout

I am not trying to do anything fancy, or change anything, but this is the issue.

I just updated site with SUPEE 6788, and now when I try and filter the orders by the order id, I get Magento error.

> Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'increment_id' in where clause is ambiguous.

I updated on test site first, and I have checked and this error didn't happen on the test site.

I last filtered on the live site a few days ago, before I ran the patch and it worked. Now it doesn't.

I have compared the `grid.php` files and they are the same as the ones on the test site. I also compared the files that were in the Magento error log, and they seem to be the same too.

I have already tried adding to `adminhtml/block/sales/orders/grid.php` `'filter_index'=>'main_table.increment_id'` and it worked.

But I don't like to edit a core file, and I don't understand why my test site is not showing the same behaviour. The only thing different it has is an older database.

Paul

Comment: Do you have any extension that modifies the admin order grid?

Answer (score 1):

In Magento version 1.9.2.2(included paths: SUPEE-6788), i view **Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Orders/Grid.php** in line 71 as `'index' => 'increment_id'`